# Negative lookbehind on a capture group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to write some regex that will allow me to do a negative lookbehind on a capture group so that I can extract possible references from emails. I need to know how to look behind from a certain point to the first white space. If a digit is found, I don't want the reference to be extracted.

I have got as far as shown below. I have 2 capture groups - 'PreRef' and 'Ref'. I don't want a 'Ref' match to be found if 'PreRef' contains a digit. What I've got so far only checks if the character immediately before the colon is a digit.

```
(?<PreRef>\S+)(?<![\d]):(?<Ref>\d{5})
```

A 'Ref' match of 12345 should be found here:

```
This is a reference:12345
```

But not here (there's a 5 in the word 'reference'):

```
This is not a ref5rence:12345
```

Comment: What is the programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude digits from the `\S` class, then surround the expression
with whitespace boundrys, then viola ..

`(?<!\S)(?<PreRef>[^\s\d]+):(?<Ref>\d{5})(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/JrU7Kd/1

Explained

```
 (?<! \S )                     # Whitespace boundary
 (?<PreRef> [^\s\d]+ )         # (1), Not whitespace nor digit
 :                             # Colon
 (?<Ref> \d{5} )               # (2), Five digits
 (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a negative lookbehind? It's easier to just exclude digits from the `PreRef` capture. `[^\W\d]` will match word characters but not digits. Then you just need to add a `\b` or other similar word boundary assertion to make sure what does match is a full word.

```
\b(?<PreRef>[^\W\d]+):(?<Ref>\d{5})
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[^\s\d]` fit better than `[^\W\d]`? Since OP uses `\S` in the question.

Comment: Using `\s` would require a more complicated zero-width assertion than `\b` since `\b` checks for word to non-word transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I surely agree with [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419892/6553328), and we can use a simple expression, if digits are not allowed prior to `:`, such as:

```
^\D+:(\d{5})
```

or:

```
^\D+:(\d{5})$
```

If we wish to add more boundaries, we can surely do that too.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/48ERTH/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^\D+:(\d{5})/gm;
const str = `This is a reference:12345
This is not a ref5rence:12345`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution didn't quite work for me because it prevents the reference being extracted where there's a digit anywhere before it, i.e. earlier in the sentence, e.g. 'This is 1 reference:12345'.